# Referencing a Configuration Admin factory-created OSGi service

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129464/7366707) by Neil Bartlett that stated that DS is able to replace the old `ManagedServiceFactory` approach of instantiating services:

> A component can be used as either a singleton (i.e. MS) or a factory (i.e. MSF) by adding "configurationPolicy: require". If you create a factory config with a Factory PID the same as the component.name, then you get a factory.

As far as I am aware, creating a new configuration with a factory PID makes the Configuration Admin create a new instance of this service; indeed, this is what happens.

Say I have a factory PID of `test`, and I then add a configuration for `test-1`  with `felix-fileinstall`. This service is then correctly instantiated and activated when I add the corresponding configuration.

If I do

```
@Reference(target="(service.pid=test-1)")
Test test;
```

this obviously never gets resolved, as the created configuration [is required to have a generated GUID](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.cm.html#i1761778).

How is it possible to obtain a reference to this service? Would I need to add an additional property to each configuration instance to filter by?

Comment: not sure if its possible to make that reference work, but if you have to write PID in your code, that probably not a good sign. I would create another property on the service config and filter by that.

Comment: Who speaks my name and awakens me from my slumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to get a reference to this specific service instance?

Generally service consumers should avoid knowing too much about the implementation behind the service, and certainly the PID that caused a component to be instantiated should be considered an internal detail of the implementation.

When obtaining a service, you care primarily about what the service does -- this is the service interface. Then you might additionally care about supplementary attributes of the service.

For example, if my pipes have burst then I need a plumber so I look for a service of type `Plumber`. If it's 2AM and I live in London then I need a 24-hour plumber so I add a filter: `(&(available=24hr)(location=London))`. I might additionally refine the filter with `(yelp_rating>=4.0)`. But I wouldn't care about the name of the plumber or what he ate for dinner.